# Passar parametros por jquery para controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um método na controller(void) que receber alguns parametros(3). Não estou conseguindo passar para o método. Das outras vezes que eu fiz, passando para um objeto lá, tenho conseguido êxito, com método retornando um json. Bem, dessa forma é um método void e não tenho um objeto como argumento, mas sim campos como argumentos. Veja abaixo o método e o jquery. Se há possibilidade de trabalhar assim também, claro.

Controller: O atributo [HttpPost] faz sentido nesse caso?

```
[HttpPost]
public void GravaPainelPesquisa(string _cnpj, string _tecnico, string _obs)
{
     V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
     T_LogCadastroPDV logcadastro = new T_LogCadastroPDV();

     logcadastro.DE_Tecnico = _tecnico;
     logcadastro.DE_Obs = _obs;

     db.T_LogCadastroPDV.Add(logcadastro);
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Meu jquery:

```
function GravaPainelPesquisa() {

    var parametros = $('#txtCnpjPesquisa').val() + ',' + $('#txtTecnicoObs').val() + ',' + $('txtObservacao').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'Pesquisa/GravaPainelPesquisa',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({  }),
        success: function (data) {

            //Aqui preciso chamar uma função que gera uma mensagem(não é um alert)
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

Função que gera a mensagem:

```
$(function () {
   $("#dialogLogPdv").dialog();
});
```

Vou trocar o botão, mas só me respondam uma coisa e veja se eu estou certo. É um botão Submit. O que passa é que os parâmetros estão vindos vazios. Coloquei um break e observo, que só para no break, após o formulário ou os controles do form serem enviados. Depois que é limpo os campos, é que entra no break, e se for o que eu estou pensando, o botão envia tudo e zera os campos e depois no método já está tudo vazio ou null. Isso, creio eu, seja uma característica do botão. Certo ou não?

Fiz assim e consegui passar os valores para o Controller:

```
var parametros = jQuery.parseJSON(' { "DE_CnpjPDV": "' + $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val() + '" , "DE_tecnico": "' + $("#txtTecnicoObs").val() +
                                      '" , "DE_Obs": "' + $("#txtObservacao").val() + '"}');
```

E no controller está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void GravaPainelPesquisa(T_LogCadastroPDV logcadastro)
        {
            V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
            logcadastro.DT_Cadastro = DateTime.Now;

            db.T_LogCadastroPDV.Add(logcadastro);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Mas mesmo assim continua dando erro no `SaveChanges();`

Esse é o erro:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

E no `EntityValidationErrors` eu pego isso:

```
{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}
```

Inner Exception está null.

Descobri o erro. Criei um try..catch e uma exception do tipo: `DbEntityValidationException` e lá vi qual é o erro. Acontece, que na view, o campo cnpj tem máscara e no BD o campo é um varchar(14), logo já sabem o que aconteceu. Tamanho maior que o suportado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cria um objeto em json para receber os valores.

```
//Obj
 var parametros =
 {
  _txtCnpjPesquisa: $('#txtCnpjPesquisa').val() ,
  _txtTecnicoObs: $('#txtTecnicoObs').val(), 
  _txtObservacao: $('txtObservacao').val()
 }

 //Post
 $.post('GravaPainelPesquisa',function(retorno){

  });
```

Crie uma classe as variáveis  deve ter o mesmo nome que a do objeto criado.

```
public class Parametros {
   string _txtCnpjPesquisa { get; set; }
   string _txtTecnicoObs { get; set; }
   string _txtObservacao { get; set; }
  }

[HttpPost]
public void GravaPainelPesquisa(Parametros parametros)
{
     V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
     db.T_LogCadastroPDV.Add(parametros);
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Sua solução funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve passar os parâmetros com o mesmo tipo e nome para que o `Router`, encontre e passe os parâmetros.

Você deve alterar a variável parâmetros assim:

```js
// cria objeto JSON para ser serializado na chama ajax
var parametros = {
    _cnpj : $('#txtCnpjPesquisa').val(),
    _tecnico: $('#txtTecnicoObs').val(),
    _obs: $('#txtObservacao').val() // tava faltando também o #, se é no caso um id
};
```

E a chamada `ajax` para passar os parâmetros por `ajax`, no `POST`:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'Pesquisa/GravaPainelPesquisa',
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(parametros), // passe aqui o objeto por parâmetro no POST
    success: function (data) {
        //Aqui preciso chamar uma função que gera uma mensagem(não é um alert)
        // chama o dialog
        $("#dialogLogPdv").dialog();
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
});
```

Método completo:

```js
function GravaPainelPesquisa() {
    var parametros = {
        _cnpj : $('#txtCnpjPesquisa').val(),
        _tecnico : $('#txtTecnicoObs').val(),
        _obs : $('#txtObservacao').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'Pesquisa/GravaPainelPesquisa',
        datatype : 'json',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(parametros),
        success : function(data) {
            //Aqui preciso chamar uma função que gera uma mensagem(não é um alert)
            $("#dialogLogPdv").dialog();
        },
        error : function(error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Hoje, do jeito que você postou, não está sendo passado os parâmetros, sendo assim é impossível que os mesmos sejam passados ao `Controller`

Comment: @pnet, depende como você quer essa mensagem, já que um alert não serve, mas dai já é outra questão, você pode dar uma olhada no [jQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @pnet, editei a resposta de uma olhada

Comment: @pnet, que erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: @pnet, o erro deve ser no contexto onde esse método se encontra, deve ter algum `(`, sem o respectivo fechamento `)`

Comment: @pnet, tava faltando também o # no `$('#txtObservacao').val()`, se é no caso um id

Comment: @pnet, esse código é javascript, você ta vendo isso né, não é C#?

Comment: @pnet, o codigo do `var parametros` que está dando erro você está colocando onde no javascript ou no C#?

Comment: Fernando, assim também deu certo. Era as chaves e não os parêntesis, para funcionar. Ok, passei, mas o erro no momento da gravação continua. Vou tentar com um using no meu contexto para ver se funfa.